# Submitting a form in rails with decimal field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem storing a field with decimal caracteristics, when the field contains a regular integer it gets stored perfectly, but when I enter a number like 88.88 the params grab it as nil, or sometimes as 8888 without the point.

```
# error
NoMethodError in Admin::ProductsController#update
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass


# schema.rb
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal  "public_price",  precision: 8, scale: 2
  end


# Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"YiAjcS2nT466GHO96QF05yyK+kcHTjPznbB4Rm4JvdHj3kdcEoYAp3wlVDmyx1PoOfDfR5/C47b1fw57BCJb+w==",
 "product"=>{"product_type"=>"product", "model"=>"E3RRss","brand"=>"MMM", "unity"=>"kg", "cost"=>"", "public_price"=>"", "desc"=>""},
"commit"=>"save",
"id"=>"7"}

# _form.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for(product, url: url) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    ....
    <%= f.input :public_price, label: "Price", required: true %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: what's the generated html?

Comment: I see the problem, I have to enter the quantity like this "88,8" with a comma...How can I change that?

Comment: that should not be the case. please post the generated html codes. I haven't used simple_form_for before.

Comment: In the form all the info is posted correctly, but :public_price get the value of nil or blank if the number is like this "9.999". If the number is like "9,9" with comma everything is ok, but I don't know why.

Comment: I am assuming `cost` field doesn't have this issue? And if you can post the generated html code it would be helpful for debugging.